# PyCharm treats os like a third party module when optimizing imports

Tags: python, pycharm

I have the following imports

```
import time
import os

import daemon
```

When I click *Code -> Optimize Imports* in PyCharm I expect it to follow [PEP 8 Imports Conventions](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#imports) (which should result in swapping `time` and `os`).

But what I get is the following:

```
import time

import daemon
import os
```

As you can see, PyCharm treats `os` module as if it was a third party module. This behavior was noticed in 2017.1 and 2017.3 versions of Pycharm.

Is this still the case in 2018.1? Or may it be some configuration problem?

Comment: PyCharm 2018.1.1 moves the `os` module up with other standard modules, just update your ide and try

Comment: PyCharm 2018.2 on Windows does it like op stated, for some odd reason.

Comment: @domenukk just installed PyCharm 2018.2 on Ubuntu, works fine. Does it work with 2018.1 on Windows? If not, then it means that this was not fixed on Windows for some reason.